# HEAD is way ahead of master

Tags: git

My `HEAD` is way ahead of `master`.
`HEAD` has the right code and `master` doesn't.
I can´t update the repository on BitBucket because it is not a fast-forward.

My history looks like:

```
|HEAD
|some commit
|some commit
|some commit
| |origin/master master
| |some commit
| |some commit
|/
some other commits...
```

How do I make my origin/master updates to HEAD witch has the right and new code?

Thanks!

Comment: First thing to ask yourself is how you managed to get a detached head in the first place so you can try to avoid that in the future

Answer (score 0):

If you don't matter about your origin/master code and you're satisfied with HEAD you can just do the following:
`git push --force`

EDIT: If there are other people on the repository you should not do that. Instead you should first `git merge master`, resolve the merge conflicts manually, commit the changes and then push them on origin/master

Comment: If there are more people using the same repository, this will make them quite unhappy.

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch new-master # mark the commit with the branch
git checkout master
git reset --hard new-master  # move master to new-master
git branch -D new-master # it's no longer needed, delete it
git push --force origin master  # Force to update the remote repo
```

Comment: like @choroba said, if there are more people on the repository they won't be happy with a force push

Comment: But you answered there his concerns. :-p

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking `HEAD` is *diverging* from `master`. And it seems `HEAD` is detached, so create a branch for backup and easy reference to its commit.

```
# "backup" can be any valid branch name you like
git branch backup HEAD
```

As `origin/master` and `master` point at the same commit, we can conclude that the commits on `master` have been published. Now you have two options.

One is to rewrite the history of `master`. It needs a force-push to update `master` in the remote repository. If there are a number of other contributors, it's not a good idea because it might bring chaotic histories if not handled properly.

```
git checkout master
git reset backup --hard
git push origin -f master
```

The other is to create a new commit on `master` and make the code exactly the same with `HEAD`. The disadvantage is the commits which are on `backup` and new to `master` might be gone if you haven't pushed them or don't intend to.

```
git checkout master
git merge $(git commit-tree -p HEAD -m "whatever" master^{tree})
# edit the commit message
git commit --amend
# later you can push as usual, without "-f"
git push origin master
```

If you want `master` to include all the commits of both `backup` and `master` and meanwhile to have the code exactly the same with `backup`, you could try

```
git checkout master
# with "-s ours", commits are merged but the changes are not
git merge backup -s ours 
# repeat the 2nd option
git merge $(git commit-tree -p HEAD -m "whatever" master^{tree})
# edit the commit message
git commit --amend
# later you can push as usual, without "-f"
git push origin master
```

As for `origin/master`, it will be updated automatically. It's okay to just leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest either

```
git merge origin/master
```

or

```
git rebase origin/master
```

With either, you may need to resolve merge conflicts, but after doing so, you will be able to push your master to BitBucket.

Rebase is slightly preferable in this case because it will keep your history linear and not show that you were working on a [detached HEAD](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head).

> It is sometimes useful to be able to checkout a commit that is not at the tip of any named branch, or even to create a new commit that is not referenced by a named branch. Let’s look at what happens when we checkout commit b (here we show two ways this may be done):
>
> ```
> $ git checkout v2.0  # or
> $ git checkout master^^
>
>   HEAD (refers to commit 'b')
>     |
>     v
> a---b---c---d  branch 'master' (refers to commit 'd')
>     ^
>     |
>   tag 'v2.0' (refers to commit 'b')
> ```
>
> Notice that regardless of which checkout command we use, `HEAD` now refers directly to commit *b*. This is known as being in detached `HEAD` state. It means simply that `HEAD` refers to a specific commit, as opposed to referring to a named branch.